# GET Method with JSON body and Bearer Authorization with RestTemplate

Tags: json, spring-boot, get, resttemplate

I know.... this is not the best practice, but i've been asked for this:

I'm trying to get an endpoint that receives a `json` body with 3 parameters `(int, int, int)` and has a Bearer Authentication.

**Headers**

```
header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
header.set("authorization", bearerToken);
```

**Entity**

```
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestjson.toString(), header);
```

**RestTemplate**

```
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

**System.out.print(entity):**

```
<{"1stParam":1,"2ndParam":4881,"3rdParam":0},{Content-Type=[application/json], authorization=[Bearer bearerToken]}>
```

besides security and all that kind of problems, the request shows a `400 HTTP` `response` via `RestTemplate`, ***Postman works fine***.

I also tried `HttpURLConnection` but had same problem.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: You can use the specific method: header.setBearerAuth(bearerToken);

Answer (score 1):

I just coded a similar solution, so I'm pretty sure I know what this is.  You have to include `Bearer` in the `Authorization` header.  I think this code change will fix your problem:

```
header.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearerToken);
```

I capitalized the header key.  I don't think this matters, but I know that the capitalized version just worked for me.  My code looks just like this, and it works.

The basic idea here is that an `Authorization` header has to always start with the kind of authorization being performed, so that the server can know kind you want to use.  It makes sense that this is a 400 error and not a 404, because the header is technically malformed.

Comment: If you say so.  There's no way of knowing from what the OP provides if that has already been done.  As he was not encoding his token in his original code, I assumed it might have already been encoded.  I was just pointing out the need to add "Bearer" and a space before the token.  These 7 characters must not be encoded.

Comment: Yes, the bearer token is encoded, i also put the "Bearer tokenCode" on the header just like my entity but still get 400 code

Comment: darn.  I thought this would be it, because I got something similar just days before.  Oh well.  No fresh ideas here.

Comment: Thanks. I think the real problem is the apache library that can't handle de JSON body on a GETrequest, so does not even sends it.
I'll keep searching.